# Uploading a picture with React.js to store in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image file from client side to MongoDB.

> I am using express server with 'multer' and 'sharp' to uploade image.
> I am using cra app for client side.

Using Postman, I can upload an image and it is stored in MongoDB.
now I am trying to upload an image from client side, which is not going well.
this is how I change the inputs, using Hook.

```
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      bday: '',
      occupation: '',
      introduction: '',
      picture: undefined,
    };
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);
    const { bday, occupation, introduction, picture } = formData;

    const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
    };
```

and the input for file upload is this.

```
    <div className='form-group'>
      <input
        className='form-input bg-light'
        name='picture'
        type='file'
        value={picture}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
```

but I have this error message as soon as I select the file

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type file to
> be controlled.

If I just submit the form ignoring that error message, I cannot upload the file.this is how i upload the file from client side.(proxy: localhost:5000)

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('avatar', picture);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };
    await axios.post('/profile/avatar', formData, config);
```

When I use Postman upload the file, setting up like following, it works fine. [image]

What should I do to upload an image file?
thank you in advance.

Comment: The warning is shown because picture is undefined in your initial state. It won't solve your problem but it's good to set the default value to an empty string for example

Comment: @Tim Gerhard, when I set picture to empty string, it gives me the same error as soon as I mount the component. whereas if I set it to undefined, after I submit the file the error occurs... so I really don't know what to do here.. lol

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working, because your `handleChange` function isn't working with a `input[type="file"]`. In your `handleChange()` you set the value of your state to `event.target.value` but your file input stores the file in `event.target.files` (if you use only one file use `e.target.files[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello change your handleChange to:

```
const handleChange = () => event => {
  console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

and for the warning it is because of the value change it form

```
<input
    className='form-input bg-light'
    name='picture'
    type='file'
    value={picture}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

to:

```
<input
    className='form-input bg-light'
    name='picture'
    type='file'
    value={formData.picture}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```